# How to show cycles in networkx graph drawing

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, networkx

I have a simple graph constructed using NetworkX as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(0,1), (0,2), (1,1), (1,2)])
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.show()
```

When I draw this graph, I get this image:

[image]

The graph also has an edge (1,1) but it does not show this edge on image. How can i draw this edge, too? I think this is the result of not using arrows. This visualization is really very bad. How can I use arrows instead of this bold lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Graphviz does a great job of drawing arrows and self loops. (Non-trivial to implement in Matplotlib).
Here is an example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(\[(0,1), (0,2), (1,1), (1,2)\])
nx.write_dot(G,'graph.dot')

# then run dot -Tpng graph.dot > graph.png
```

[image]

Comment: I get ImportError: ('requires pygraphviz ', 'http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz ', '(not available for Python3)')
So is this going to be a feature going forward?

Comment: To use networkx.write_dot() you also need either pygraphviz or pydot.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write_dot'` in networkx version 1.11 and I have both pygraphviz and pydot installed.  Which version is this?

Comment: use `from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot`

Comment: `from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot` did not help me. Same AttributeError.