# how do I draw selfloops using Networkx and matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, networkx

I am using networkx and trying to find cycles in graphs.
I wrote the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

tg = nx.Graph()

h_lat_dir = {1: [("A", "A"), ("B", "B"), ("A", "B")], 2: [("C", "D")],
    3: [("C", "F")], 4: [("F", "F")], 5: [("C", "C"), ("C", "E"), ("D", "E"), ("E", "E")],
    6: [("D", "D")]}

for wght, edgelist in h_lat_dir.iteritems():
    tg.add_edges_from(edgelist, weight=wght)

print nx.cycle_basis(tg)


nx.write_dot(tg, 'multi.dot')
nx.draw_graphviz(tg)
pylab.show()
```

the result is

```
[['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['F'], ['E', 'D', 'C'], ['D'], ['E']]
```

and this drawing
[image]

Why can't I see the self_loops? (every vertex has one)
Is it possible to draw them somehow?

Comment: If you can use graphviz here is an approach (requires pygraphviz or pydot) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312334/how-to-show-cycles-in-networkx-graph-drawing/22315199#22315199

Comment: The example you provided works on Digraph. Mine is undirected.

Answer (score 2):

Using the NetworkX interface to Graphviz (through pygraphviz or pydot):

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0,1), (0,2), (1,1), (1,2)])
nx.write_dot(G,'graph.dot')
```

Then run

```
dot -Tpng graph.dot > graph.png
```

[image]

Comment: I copy paste your code, run the command and still get a directed - no self looped graph ???

Comment: Could you show the output dot file and associated drawing?

Comment: graph.dot:
strict digraph  {
 0 -> 1;
 0 -> 2;
 1 -> 2;
}
and the image (how can I upload it here???) is like yours with directed edges 0->1 0->2 1->2 and no edge 1->1

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with the pygraphviz or pydot (not sure which one you are using) installation.  If you use nx.Graph() and send that to nx.write_dot() you should get a graph not a digraph in the dot output.

Comment: Sad that it is still not possible to do many years after =( I was hoping that networkx was the tool to switch from graphviz, I want to have some easy way to interactively draw graphs based on adj matrix and generating dot and processingt it with graphviz is a no-go.