# Undirected graph with self-loop in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I wanna make an undirected graph with several self-loops in NetworkX and display it, but I couldn't find any example in NetworkX documentation. Even when I googled it, couldn't find anything. Could you give an example for making and visualizing a graph with self-loop in NetworkX?

Comment: have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312334/how-to-show-cycles-in-networkx-graph-drawing?

Comment: is your question about making the graph or visualizing it?

Comment: @Joel both! I wanna make a graph with a few self-loops and visualize it