# I can not draw edges of the form (i, i) in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

When I add edges of the form: G.add_edge (2,2), for example, when trying to plot this edge, netoworkx ignores it and does not draw it. This doing something wrong ?. I am new to python and using networx please help. This happens whenever I add edges of the form G.add_edge (i, i). I'm using G = nx.MultiGraph ()

Comment: Are you plotting the graph with `matplotlib`? If so, you aren't going to get good drawings for the graph. You should try `graphviz` for better graph plotting, as it actually shows self-edges. See for e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312334/how-to-show-cycles-in-networkx-graph-drawing

Comment: Networkx doesn't draw self-edges.  See other related questions on this.