# drawing a reflexive graph using networkx and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

How can a reflexive graph be drawn with networkx and matplotlib? In other words, vertex "A" connects to itself and should have an curved arrow pointing back to itself. Can this be done with networkx and maptplotlib? I'm open to using other python libraries but would prefer networkx.

[image]

Here is the code I have now which draws A but without the reflexive edge.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()
# Add node A pointing back to itself
G.add_edges_from([('A','A')])
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, arrows=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312334/how-to-show-cycles-in-networkx-graph-drawing/22315199#22315199